# How do i keep the label updated as the time passes in ios

Tags: ios, nsdate

> How do i keep the UILabel updated as the time passes when a post is posted in ios ..like if >its posted just now it should say 0s and as time passes it changes to >1min,2min...1hr,2hr...1day and so in ios
>   I am new to the ios development
>   Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) for this purpose if I understand your questions properly.

Comment: i have a custom table view cell which has a label for comments and for the time(when posted), now if a user types in a comment it shows the comment by adding a row into the uitableview but how do i set the time on the table thats the problem..the time must be compared with the current time and accordingly the uilabel should change

Comment: I think your UITableView has nothing to do with the time, if you are using some label inside the table to set the date or time, then you just have to update the label value depending on the timer & date interval.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something on a regular interval is pretty easy in iOS.

In your main code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                                 target: self
                               selector: @selector(doSomething:)
                               userInfo: nil
                                repeats: YES];
```

Then add the doSomething method:

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSLog(@"We did it!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to keep the date when user posted. You can easily do that by using:

```
NSDate* postedDate = [NSDate now];
```

Than if you want to find a seconds left from that time you can use:

```
NSTimeInterval timeDiff = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:postedDate];
```

This gives you seconds from posting date - you need to format output.

For keeping label updating itself you should use NSTimer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0f
                                 target: self
                               selector: @selector(updateLabel:)
                               userInfo: nil
                                repeats: YES];
```

Where updateLabel will format "timeDiff" into something human readable like 1minute / day etc...

Comment: yes..but does it chnage the uilabel accordingly? Like in facebook when we post a comment it shows 0s ago and as the time passes it keeps updating the uilabel

Comment: You have to connect updateLabel: to really update a label - it won't do it self - and set text according to timeDiff. I cannot give you ready to use solution - that depends heavily on how your classes looks like and how your application design is done. For example: if you have custom table cell - you should make NSStimer on initializing cell and implement updateLabel on your custom cell class.

Comment: yes i have a custom table view cell which has a label for comments and for the time(when posted), now if a user types in a comment it shows the comment by adding a row into the uitableview but how do i set the time on the table thats the problem..the time must be compared with the current time and accordingly the uilabel should change

Comment: Than you need to keep a posted date for your UITableView with the last post done and do as I suggested above. With timeIntervalSinceDate you can get time that passed from last post. I don't know where you still have a problem, sorry.